# CiviCRM Installer doesn't find language files

Tags: wordpress, localisation

I am trying to install CiviCRM 4.7.8 on WordPress 4.5.2.

I uploaded the l10n and sql folder to the civicrm folder, but the installer only offers "English (United States)" as an option for "Language of basic data:" :-(

I spent many hours to get this working, without any success :-( Is it a bug of CiviCRM???

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, the red error messages are gone after changing the php version from 7 to 5.6. But I am still unable to select a different language! :(

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I forgot to upload "civicrm_data.de_DE.mysql". I only uploaded the "civicrm_acl.de_DE.mysql" to the sql folder.

Comment: You can accept your answer as the best answer...